# Ubuntu running as router blocks VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, firewall, router

I have a Ubuntu server 16.01 running as my router, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXX5gCi0uTo

everything works fine, every machine gets an IP, I have internet connection and even playing online I have zero lag,

but now that I want to connect to my job's VPN I've got this error:

[a connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the ports used for this connection was closed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVGaZ.png)

how should i open the ports for the VPN? :(

what rule am I missing in my iptables?

```
~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
Logging    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain Logging (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/sec burst 10 LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**Edit 1:**
I removed the Logging chain and it still not working.

**Edit 2:**

```
~$ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 44132 packets, 12M bytes)
 pkts bytes target  prot opt in     out     source      destination
51909   12M ACCEPT  all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
7840K   11G ACCEPT  all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
12130 4281K ACCEPT  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target  prot opt in     out     source      destination
 921K   93M ACCEPT  all  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
1282K 1176M ACCEPT  all  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 203K packets, 44M bytes)
 pkts bytes target  prot opt in     out     source      destination
```

---

```
~$ sudo iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 57056 packets, 14M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11567 packets, 2020K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23793 packets, 2413K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 11983 packets, 1286K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source    destination
22262 2006K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Maybe if you post the output of `iptables -nvL` it could be more helpful; also, as your machine is your router, you could also attach the output of `iptables -t nat -nvL`

Comment: @Eduar done! :D